# Как сделать QChart добавленный на QGraphicsScene растягиваемым?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, gui

Имею данный код:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtCharts>

using namespace QtCharts;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //
    QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();
    series->append(0, 6);
    series->append(2, 4);
    series->append(3, 8);
    series->append(7, 4);
    series->append(10, 5);
    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->legend()->hide();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->createDefaultAxes();
    chart->setTitle("Simple line chart example");
    //

    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    scene->addItem(chart);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Имею данный дизайн:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать график растягиваемым? Желательно без лишних классов и прочего, как можно проще.

Comment: А обязательно на сцену размещать? Мб просто [на виджет установить](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtcharts-areachart-main-cpp.html)?